# React context api how to split up data to different child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm currently working on an application where I need to use the context API to pass states to various child components.

In the parent component, I have the following states

```js
state = {
  id: string,
  textarea: {
    ref: RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement>,
    editing: boolean,
    updateEditing: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>,
    value: string,
    updateValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>
  },
  menu: {
    showIterate: boolean,
    updateShowIterate: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>,
    showActions: boolean,
    updateShowIterate: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>
  },
  // ...some other states
}
```

In Parent.tsx

```js
export const ParentContext = createContext({})

...logics

return (
  <ParentContext.Provider value={state}>
    <Menu />
    <Textarea />
    <Data />
  </ParentContext.Provider>
)
```

Right now, the `Menu` child component only needs the menu part of the state. But when that changes, it would re-render the `Textarea` and `Data` components because the context value has changed. How can I split up the context data so that only values in the state that affect the child component using it re-render the child component?

Comment: If the components that need the pieces of the context are direct children of where the context is set, you’re not getting any benefit anyway because 1. changing the state in the Provider (the …logics part) would be enough to cause the children to re-render anyway and 2. There’s no “prop drilling” to be avoided, they’re direct children. Just pass the pieces as props and eschew the context entirely. Also, don’t focus on “number of renders” unless you either have or know you will have a performance issue. It’s not worth your time

Comment: I know I didn’t answer your question, which sometimes annoys people, but because of the way your component tree is structured, there’s actually no way (that isn’t really really contrived) to split up the context to prevent re-rendering of the other children because the state is all held in the same parent. You can split up the context in a different way that would allow it, but you’d need separate contexts for each piece of state AND you’d have to restructure your component tree in a really hideously ugly way that I’m not going to bother mentioning because it’s so absurd